# Call different type of questions from database as per their category

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, jquery

I am developing Multiple Choice Questions (M.C.Q.) web application in which I want to ask random questions from three different category. suppose I want to ask 15 question in test in that test there must be 5 questions from cat-1, then 5, 5 from cat-2, cat-3 respectively. I tried it but I am able to get them on one single page which I don't want so I want to show them using pagination.

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: paste your code so that we know what you tried for this.

Comment: Maybe that answer is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12448936/652669

Comment: @sskoko its confidential data so can't show sorry for that but what i got is one question below that there options then again question below options like this 20 question i am able to show it. now i just want to show them on pagination. but not all 20 question only one question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist which questions you've already asked somehow (session, database, etc). One way to do this is to generate the test, store it on the db, and return the test I'd with the first question. Then every subsequent request asks for the test id & the next question in the sequence.